# Swift UITapGesture on view in a titleView not working

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I have a UINavigationItem and I set it's titleView to a UIView which has a UILabel and UIImageView embedded. I'm attempting to add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the view but it doesn't seem to work. Any solutions? Also, adding a gestureRecognizer to the whole navigationBar isn't an option as I have a rightBarButtonItem and want to make use of the back button.

Here is my code:

```
func configureTitleView() {
    guard let profile = profile else { 
    // Pop navController
    return
  }

    let titleView = UIView()
    titleView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40)

    let containerView = UIView()
    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    titleView.addSubview(containerView)

    let profileImageView = UIImageView()
    profileImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    profileImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    let imageURL = URL(string: profile!.firstProfilePicture!)
    profileImageView.sd_setImage(with: imageURL)

    containerView.addSubview(profileImageView)

    profileImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 36).isActive = true
    profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 36).isActive = true

    profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 36 / 2

    let nameLabel = UILabel()

    containerView.addSubview(nameLabel)
    nameLabel.text = profile!.displayName!
    nameLabel.textColor = .white
    nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    nameLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.rightAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    nameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    nameLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    nameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

    containerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    containerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.openProfile))
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    titleView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    titleView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code how you are adding the all those items in the navigation bar ? I hope you are adding tap gesture to the background view and the imageview and label are above those view and so the gesture is not responding.

Comment: One suggestion, Instead of tap gesture you could try adding a button with clear color like you add the other two and add target for the button.

Comment: @Bharath I've added my code... Is there an approach I can take without using a button?

Comment: Is this happening only on iOS 11?

Comment: @beyowulf I've tested only on iOS 11 and I wouldn't be surprised if it was also a bug in iOS 10.

Comment: There are some warnings in autolayout when I debugged the view heirarchy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beginning with iOS 11, views added to toolbars as `UIBarButtonItem` using `UIBarButtonItem(customView:)` are now laid out using auto layout. This includes title views added to a `UINavigationBar` through the `navigationItem.titleView` property of a `UIViewController`. You should add sizing constraints on your `titleView`. For example:

```
titleView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
titleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0).isActive = true
```

Otherwise, auto layout will use the intrinsic content size of your title view which is `CGSize.zero`. Gestures are masked to the bounds of the view they are attached to even if the sub views of that view are not. Because the bounds of `titleView` without constraints is `CGRect.zero` it will never fire. Add constraints and it works as expected.

For more information see the WWDC 2017 session [Updating your app for iOS 11](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/204/).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to add explicit height and width constant constraint to custom view.

Just add subviews to custom view, add width and height anchor.

```
    let customView = UIView()

    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    customView.addSubview(button)

    [
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.widthAnchor),
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.heightAnchor),
        ].forEach({$0.isActive = true})

    navigationItem.titleView = customView
```